# Can't send mails with BCC using mailx "illegal option -- b"

Tags: aix, mailx

I'm trying to BCC e-mails through unix using the following command.

```
echo "E-mail message" | mailx -r Senders@Address.com -s "E-mails Subject" ~b BCC_Receiver@Address.com
```

But I get the error `~b... User unknown`.

If I use `-b` instead of `~b`, I get the error `illegal option -- b`

If I use *mail* instead of *mailx*, I get exactly the same erros.

However, when I try it interactively in the following way, it works.

```
mail -r Senders@Address.com -s Subject Receivers@Address.com
~b BCC_Receiver
E-mail message
.
CC:
```

I'd like to make this work in a single command. How can I do this?

When I type `uname -a`, this is the output: `s00va9939577 1 7 00CD96834C00`.

Comment: I'm really new to UNIX, so I'm expecting my question to be missing some important information (for instance which version I am on - I don't know how to check, if you need this, please tell me how I can find it out). Please ask anything you want to know. I also ask that whoever is qualified enough tags my question appropriately. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might have seen this from a book with a printing error or some bad UTF code. The `~b` refers to the home directory of a user named `b`.

Comment: You need to run the command `man mailx` to read the documentation for the mailx command. The "man page" will tell you what are the valid options.

Comment: It might also be useful to run the command `uname -a` and post the output in your answer so we can have an idea about what kind of system you're running on.

Comment: @Otheus I understood what you said, but I can't contemplate that information in conjunction with the interactive bit in my question. As I see it `~b` did work.

Comment: Relevant details posted as comments can easily be obscured. It's much better to improve your answer by [editing it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/285406/edit).

Comment: @Noob, right, sorry. The `~b` doesn't work on the command line. The shell expands it into a directory, which mailx then treates as a _filename argument_. But, the user doesn't exist, so the shell kindly refuses to run the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-b` option, to specify addresses on the command line, does not appear to be supported on your version.

Your second, interactive example works because `mailx` recognises it as  tilde escape.  These have to appear as the first thing on the line in the message body, rather than on the command line.  They're in the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mailx.html), so they are more widely supported.

> The following commands can be entered only from input mode, by beginning a line with the escape character (by default, <tilde> ( '˜' ))
>
> [...]
>
> **~b** *name . . .*
>
> Add the names to the blind carbon copy (Bcc) list.

Answer (score 0):

there is no `~b` used as a switch to mailx on any unix platform that I know of. Correct command should look something like this:

```
echo -e "email message body" | mail -s 'subject' -b bcc_address_1@server1.com,bcc_address_2@server2.com visible_to_address@server.com
```

Comment: The OP did mention trying `-b` and getting an error...

Comment: MelBurslan, as @StephenKitt pointed out. I already tried this and I get the error described in the question.